# confusión pasando a formato iso una fecha dentro de una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo la cadena "30 del 04 para el 2018"

Tengo que eliminar las palabras y que la fecha me quede en **formato** iso *yyyy-mm-dd*

**¿Cómo se puede hacer?** Todo me da error

```
cadena="30 del 04 para el 2018"
prueba=re.findall(r'[0-9.-]', cadena)
prueba
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siguiendo con tu ejemplo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import re
cadena="30 del 04 para el 2018"
parsed=re.findall('\d+', cadena)
fecha_final = parsed[-1] + '-' + parsed[1] +'-' + parsed[0]
print(fecha_final)
```

**Salida:**

```
'2018-04-30'
```

### Explicación

- `\d`: le indicamos que solo busque los digitos de la cadena
- `+`: le indicamos que coja 1 o más repeticiones de un patron seguidas, en este caso números
- Por último para crear `fecha_final` accedemos a las distintas posiciones de la lista para reordenar la fecha con el formato *yyyy-mm-dd*

Para más información se puede leer la [documentación oficial sobre expresiones regulares y Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 3):

Si bien las respuestas que ya tienes son las adecuadas a tu pregunta, quiero dar un poco más de detalle a la cuestión de fondo, acerca de los errores de tu código.

El primer tema a mencionar, desconozco si realmente es un problema real, es la falta del `import` del módulo de expresiones regulares, es decir: `import re`, el otro problema, es el patrón que  estás usando `[0-9.-]`, esto "matchea" caracteres numéricos de forma individual, por lo que el resultado sería una lista con estos:

```
['3', '0', '0', '4', '2', '0', '1', '8']
```

Con un pequeño ajuste a tu patrón : `[0-9.-]+`  o mucho mejor `\d+` "matcheas" todos los números contiguos:

```
['30', '04', '2018']
```

Mucho mejor no? ahora es mucho más fácil convertir este formato a uno ISO, lo más simple es una sencilla concatenación en el orden apropiado:

```
fecha_iso = "{2}-{1}-{0}".format(*prueba)
print(fecha_iso)

2018-04-30
```

Answer (score 3):

A pesar de que tu pregunta ya ha sido completamente respondida, comentaré una alternativa que no ha sido contemplada.

No necesitas usar expresiones regulares para lograr lo que quieres. Todo lo que necesitas está en el módulo `datetime`. Específicamente, necesitas la función `strptime()`, la cual cuenta con un poderosísimo parser capaz de convertir una string en un objeto de tipo `datetime`, a partir de un [formato](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) dado.

Después, puedes convertir este objeto de tipo `datetime` a uno de tipo `date`, para luego devolver la string que deseas mediante la invocación del método `isoformat()`.

**Código:**

```py
from datetime import datetime


cadena = '30 del 04 para el 2018'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(cadena, '%d del %m para el %Y')
date_object = datetime_object.date()

print(date_object.isoformat())
```

**Salida:**

```
'2018-04-30'
```

Answer (score 2):

Si el formato de la fecha en la cadena es siempre el mismo, puedes probar:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

cadena = "30 del 04 para el 2018"
dia, mes, anyo = re.search("(\d+)+ del (\d+) para el (\d+)", cadena).groups()
datetime(int(anyo), int(mes), int(dia)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Utiliza una expresión regular para extraer el día, mes y año de la cadena y luego la función `strftime` de `datetime` para imprimir la fecha en el formato que tú quieres.